# custom google maps api icon, as html tags?

Tags: google-maps

I wonder if I could make a defualt icon in google api as  html (like drawing html+ css stuff on top of the map and then animate it in CSS3 and JQuery..?

such as :

```
var html = '<div style="width: 50px; height: 40px; background-color: red;"></div>';

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.990191, 34.756335);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: TheMap,
       icon: html
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done.

In your example you would need to create a 50px by 40px red image and include it on your site.

However assuming the reason for your question is to create something a little more dynamic (perhaps different colours for each one). My suggestion would be to create a page server side which would accept query string parameters.

```
var colour = 'red';
var url = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/MyImageHandler.asix?colour=' + colour;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.990191, 34.756335);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: TheMap,
   icon: url 
});
```

I'm a .NET geek so in our world we'd create HttpHandler and set it up to respond to requests at MyImageHandler.asix. It would then look at the query string parameter and create an appropriate image.

I don't really want to go into too much more detail without knowing your back end languages (if any). Hope this helps.

Comment: i do know back end language (also .net ;) ), however, did you mean in your example that var url is "html" ?  and its generate an image ?   another question I might have is that if it cant be done, does it render it as a background-image so I cannot use animate gif as well ?

Comment: You're right - copy and paste error! I believe you can use an animated gif but you're fairly limited on the transparency (no partial transparency support) - I've seen another Q on SO giving details of how to do it but don't have it to hand. In the end I abandoned that idea and went with the approach I outlined above instead.